# Lazy Loading Dylibs

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing a c++ command line tool for Mac OS 10.5+ with XCode 3.2.5 that is written like this :-

```
int main()
{
    ...
    if (a == b)
    {
        doWork() // defined in my.dylib
        doOtherWork() // defined in his.dylib
    }
}
```

However it crashes even when a and b are not equal:-

```
Lab-Computer-9adf72:tmp labuser$ ./myapp 
dyld: Library not loaded: ./my.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/./myapp
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

Is there a way to make the app work at least when the functions are not called? Or make the loading happen only lazily?

There are multiple such functions being called from multiple dylibs so a per function check would be the last resort but even that would help.

Comment: All your dynamic loading functions have return values that allow you to conclude whether or not a load succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you load the library dynamically with `dlopen`. You should then use `dlsym` to get the address of a symbol (function) by name. So you would do that:

```
void (*doWork)();
void (*doOtherWork)();

int main() {
    doWork = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "doWork");
    doOtherWork = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "doOtherWork");
    if (a == b) {
        if (doWork) doWork();
        if (doOtherwork) doOtherWork();
    }
}
```

You can get more information here: [Mac OS X ABI Dynamic Loader Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Many many thanks for the reply. While I don't load it with dlopen it looks like the way to go. When the dylibs are available the app works nicely whether or not a equals b. Is there a commandline option that I can make the code, as posted, work.

Comment: @Himanshu, do you know that, in English, a question is always ended with question mark, or '?'?

Comment: You could try weak linking, but I don't know how you would test if the library has correctly been loaded. I would recommend using `dlopen` to load dynamic library that may not be available.

Comment: I'll go with the dlopen although the compile option was more tempting as it allowed the same little code to work on Windows and Mac. And of course testing loaded would have been a problem.

Comment: I think it makes sense to mention that `-Wl,-lazy-lXXX` or `-Wl,-lazy_library,XXX` which were meant to implement lazy loaded libraries in the past have been removed from Xcode.